# Angular 2 *ngFor not displaying data

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I can't seem to get the data in **this.heroes** to display on the list. I put an **alert(this.heroes[0].name);** and it did display the data so **this._service.getHeroes();** is returning the data

**app.html**

```
<div style="width:1000px;margin:auto">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
            <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {HeroService} from './heroes/hero.service';
import {Hero} from './heroes/hero';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html',
    providers: [HeroService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent {
    heroes: Hero[];

    constructor(private _service: HeroService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.heroes = this._service.getHeroes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the `alert()`? Can you make a plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Did this work with the old ng-repeat="hero in heroes". Read this for reference: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-ng-for-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first and see if it works:

```
<li ng-repeat="hero in heroes">
    {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

If this works you might have an older angular version that does not support the *ngFor syntax yet (I think this is supported in the new version angular 2).

Comment: Thanks Lisa I'll try it. Its also occurred to me that I might need a number property for *ngFor to work. My Heores class only has a string property for name.

Comment: My package.json and index.html weren't properly configured for Angular 2 and dependencies. It works fine now. Thanks Lisa

Comment: Ah! I see. I'll keep this in mind when I switch to angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a little more research and no data is displaying. For example:

```
<h2>My favorite hero is {{ myHero }}</h2>
```

gets a blank line (where myHero is a populated string) whereas

```
<h2>My favorite hero is </h2>
```

displays

My favourite hero is

I'm going to change the Beta version of Angular 2 to see if it helps